# Why does the computer ignore my program?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void positive(int input, int t);
void negative(int input, int t);

void main(){

    int input,t;

    clrscr();

    textcolor(YELLOW);

    cprintf("ENTER YOUR NUMBER: ");

    scanf("%i",&input);

    cprintf("\nNUMBER IN WORD(S): ");

    if (input < -9999 && input > 9999) // <------ THIS GUY
      printf("INVALID ENTRY, PROGRAM TERMINATED"); // <-------- AND ALSO THIS THING


    if(input == 0)
      printf("Zero");

    if(input < 0 && input >-10000){
        negative(input,t);
    }
    if(input > 0 && input <10000){
        positive(input,t);
    }

    getch();
}
```

This is the main function of my code, it has other functions but whenever a user types an integer either less that -9999 and greater that 9999 the print command is not appearing on the screen but the program is up and running it just ignores the code.

EXAMPLE:

Enter a Number: 123151 Your number in Word: 
no answer.

What to fix here?

Comment: `input < -9999 && input > 9999` always false.

Comment: How can `input` be less than `-9999` *and* larger than `9999` *at the same time*?

Comment: You need to use `||` instead of `&&`. Also, avoid using `conio.h` since it is non-standard.

Comment: Nice title. Computer says .... don't care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace following 'if' condition

```
 if (input < -9999 && input > 9999)
```

with

```
 if (input < -9999 || input > 9999)
```